# Initialization wrong class

Tags: ios, objective-c

i class

```
Collections *tempLocalCollection = [[Collections alloc] init];
```

the problem is that when I try to promote an attribute in sequent way

```
 tempLocalCollection.id = [f numberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"0"]];            
 tempLocalCollection.action = @"client_insert";
```

I should be in error

> -[Collections setId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xff8afb0 2015-09-16 10:25:14.235 App[1042:128375] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Collections setId:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xff8afb0'

where am I wrong ?

Collections.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Items;

@interface Collections : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * datetime_creation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * datetime_last_update_client;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * datetime_last_update_server;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * local_delete;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * action;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * labelServer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * ref_user;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * sorting;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * system;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *collection_item;
@end

@interface Collections (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

@end
```

Collections.m

```
#import "Collections.h"
#import "Items.h"


@implementation Collections

@dynamic datetime_creation;
@dynamic datetime_last_update_client;
@dynamic datetime_last_update_server;
@dynamic local_delete;
@dynamic action;
@dynamic id;

@dynamic label;
@dynamic labelServer;
@dynamic ref_user;
@dynamic sorting;
@dynamic system;
@dynamic collection_item;

@end
```

This is the method that uses the class and where it goes wrong.
I think the context is the same right?

```
-(Collections *) upgrateListCollection:(NSDictionary *) coll{
    NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
    NSNumber *id = [f numberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", coll[@"id"]]];
    Collections *tempLocalCollection = [[Collections alloc] init];
    NSArray *tmp = [Collections MR_findByAttribute:@"id" withValue:id];
    if(tmp.count != 0){
        tempLocalCollection = tmp[0];
    }
        if(!tempLocalCollection.isAccessibilityElement){
            tempLocalCollection.id = [f numberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"0"]];

            tempLocalCollection.action = @"client_insert";
        }else{
            if([tempLocalCollection.local_delete isEqual: @"1"]){
                tempLocalCollection.action = @"client_delete";
            }else{
                if([tempLocalCollection.label isEqual:coll[@"label"]]){
                    if(tempLocalCollection.datetime_last_update_client < coll[@"datetime_last_update_server"]){
                        tempLocalCollection.action = @"client_update";
                    }else{
                        tempLocalCollection.action = @"server_update";
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    if(tempLocalCollection != nil){
        tempLocalCollection.labelServer = coll[@"label"];
        tempLocalCollection.datetime_last_update_server = coll[@"datetime_last_update_server"];
        tempLocalCollection.datetime_creation = coll[@"creation_utc_server"];
    }

    return tempLocalCollection;
}
```

Comment: Where is defined `id` of `Collections`? .h ? .m ?

Comment: a managed object must be created within a managed object context. you should never alloc/init it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSManagedObject` subclass (`Collections`) properties are dynamic, their setter and getter are [generated at runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtDynamicResolution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH102-SW1)

Thus when you create object of `Collections` using `alloc/init` in that case the dynamic properties are not created hence you get the exception `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

The right way of creating a `NSManagedObject` is

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Collections" inManagedObjectContext:myMOC];
Collections *collection = (Collections *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:myMOC];
```

And if you want to create a temporary object of `Collections` then pass `nil` as manage object context

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Collections" inManagedObjectContext:myMOC];
Collections *tempObj = (Collections *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

Comment: It's your manage object context, generally we use the one which is created in the app delegate file. You can access using application app delegate

Comment: one last thing : if I insert an attribute in the Collections class that I have on the table in db , the system breaks . Why? I need another attribute to save a value temporarily

Answer (score 0):

That is a managed object and needs to be created in its managing context.